# Where is a off-chain transactions stored?

Tags: blockchain, ether

I don't fully understand off chain transactions.
They do not need to be verified by other validators/nodes.
Okay that doesn't seem like a big deal, but then I read this: [Off-chain does not necessarily mean not on the blockchain, it just means that it's not on the public blockchain](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbestechcouncil/2019/09/06/on-chain-versus-off-chain-the-perpetual-blockchain-governance-debate/?sh=73ac45bc1f5e).

Isn't the entire blockchain public? What parts are not?
I don't get how you could have transactions private, and not validated, influencing and interacting with variables/gas/eth on the public chain.

For example, what if two people have a modified transaction that produces more gas for both of them. This isn't validated by anyone, then they go and spend that on the main chain?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Anyone can set-up private blockchains between their friends and family, or for a corporation. Transactions that take place in a private blockchain (or off-chain) need not be considered by the public blockchain since they will not impact its state.

Comment: There are several L2 solutions some of them could be interpreted as off-chain transaction in the sense that their transaction aren't available in the main chain. But transactions could be validated in the L2 chain.